# installing j2ee Agent on Windows 7

Tags: windows, tomcat, environment-variables, agent, opensso

I'm trying to install j2ee Agent 3 for Tomcat in Windows 7. I try to open agentadmin batch file to start the installation, but the program only flashes on the screen and disappears with no impact. Is this a compability issue? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set up JAVA_HOME environment variable